# Where to put code of "smart request" do database in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have something like this:

in my view:

```
<%= render :partial => 'show', :locals => { :employee => flash[:selection][:employee] } %>
```

in my partial 'show':

```
<p>
  <b>Manager:</b>
  <%= Employee.find(employee.employee_id).first_name %> <%= Employee.find(employee.employee_id).last_name %>
</p>
```

---

**Question:**
I feel like it's not good approach to ask something from model (like: Employee.find(employee.employee_id).first_name) in the partial... And seems like in a view also... Is it right?
*Where should I put such code of "smart request" to database and how then should I call it from partial?*

**UPD1**
I did something like you advised previously...
In my controller before rendering that view (which consequently will render partial), I find this employee and put it into  flash[:selection][:employee]... 
This employee has much columns, like: first_name, last_name, ..., and finally employee_id. The latter employee_id is the manager of current employee (flash[:selection][:employee]).
I want to show all employee's fields in my partial. So I passed flash[:selection][:employee] like employee to the partial, then show there all stuff like: employee.first_name, ... And finally i want to show this employee.employee_id not like integer id, but actually find in database correspondent employee and put its first and last names... 
Ok before rendering my view, i can set not only @employee, but also its @manager, and then pass these values to my partial... 
But... this seems a bit "too much done just to show in one place this @manager's first and last names... 
Am i right? or this is common usage in rails, isn't it?

Comment: why don't you have an assoaition connect employee to its manager ?

Comment: thanks Frederick, i don't know what is association, but i will try to figure out, thanks for direction!

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in the controller that is rendering that view.  Initialize an instance variable in your controller action and this will be accessible from your view and partials. Something like this:

```
@employee = Employee.find(...)
```

In recent version of Rails, passing that instance variable to a partial would be as easy as:

```
<%= render 'show', :employee => @employee %>
```

Then in your partial, you would do:

```
<p>
  <b>Manager:</b>
  <%= employee.first_name %> <%= employee.last_name %>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for advise... 
Sorry, seems like I missed some details in my original question description... Please look my UPD1 above...

Comment: It seems you should define an association between employee and manager, and therefore you could be able to do stuff like employee.manager.first_name from your partial.

Comment: ok, big thanks for the direction to go!
I will google "rails association" and will try to do this!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  You shouldn't be using finders in views.  Initialize the variable that the view needs to work with in the controller.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, I solved the problem, providing the following association:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...

  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => "employee_id"
end
```

and then make the correspondent call from partial:

```
employee.manager.first_name
```